# Coldfusion server error - Corrupt form data: premature ending

Tags: coldfusion

I've got a problem with our live server. Occasionally a page will not load, and the following error is displayed in plain black text on a white background:

```
 Server Error
 The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request
 Application server is busy. Either there are too many concurrent requests
```

If I look in the error log for the website, at the time of the error using the following command:

```
 grep "12:17:33" error_log
```

lines such as this are returned:

```
 [Tue May 03 12:17:33 2011] [notice] jrApache[14352: 21512]  returning error page for JRun too busy or out of memory
```

Then if I search in the Coldfusion cfserver.log I find these errors, a few seconds before hand:

05/03 12:17:29 error Corrupt form data: premature ending
java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending
        at com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser.(MultipartParser.java:177)
        at com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser.(MultipartParser.java:99)
        at coldfusion.filter.FormScope.fillMultipart(FormScope.java:190)
        at coldfusion.filter.FusionContext.SymTab_initForRequest(FusionContext.java:369)
        at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:33)
        at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
        at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:53)
        at coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)
        at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
        at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
        at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
        at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
        at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
        at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
        at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
        at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
        at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
        at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
        at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
        at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
        at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)

05/03 12:17:29 error (JRun Service: ProxyService [jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService@500b675]) JRunPRoxyServer.invokeRunnable:
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at jrun.servlet.JRunResponse.getWriter(JRunResponse.java:205)
        at jrun.servlet.JRunResponse.sendError(JRunResponse.java:597)
        at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:328)
        at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
        at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
        at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)

java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at jrun.servlet.JRunResponse.getWriter(JRunResponse.java:205)
        at jrun.servlet.JRunResponse.sendError(JRunResponse.java:597)
        at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:328)
        at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
        at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
        at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)

I don't really know what to do from here.

If the page is refreshed then it loads without error. I don't know how to replicate the error, it doesn't seem to happen on any particular page or at any articular time.

I've tried setting:

```
 Maximum number of simultaneous Template requests: 100
```

in the Coldfusion administrator, I've done that based on Steven Erat's post: http://www.talkingtree.com/blog/index.cfm/2005/3/11/ContextSwitchingBad

But I'm still getting errors. Would increasing this to a higher value help?

And then there's the "premature form ending" part of the longer Java error, I'm not sure if that's related and don't understand what it means anyway.

I've also looked through my access logs, and ruling out any images or js files that get called at the time of any errors, I've got a variety of CFM pages that return a 503 http status, and some of them are CFM pages that get returned with a content type of Javascript, and are never requested after a form post.

So in summary, I'm getting some pretty blunt error messages, and I can reproduce them at present, and the page loads fine if I just hit F5, and I'd like to know if anyone can help me to understand the source of the problem.

Oh and one last thing, we're running a RHEL 5 server with CF9, and we've upgraded recently from CF7. Before the upgrade this error was not happening.

Comment: I installed FusionReactor today, it asked me to install a new JRE at the same time and I did. Then I had to reboot coldfusion.

Comment: I've not had the error since, but now don't know which of those three things have solved the problem. I imagine not the reboot, as I've done that before, although it might have just temporarily freed up the RAM? Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really sorry to answer this myself, and I'm not entirely sure what fixed it.

But I installed FusionReactor, which required me updating my JVM, and then rebooting coldfusion. Since then, the problem has not occurred.

I was getting it daily, at least hourly but at peak times a couple of times a minute. Now it hasn't happened in 5 days.

I'd love to hear any thoughts on why any of these might have fixed it?

Comment: Thats not a problem, at least you posted the solution!

Comment: I uninstalled FR recently, 500 errors started coming back. Reinstalled FR, they've gone again. I should really try to find out why FR is fixing it.

Comment: I get the same error when I run a cfloop that creates 400 datasources using adminapi. Does FR add any arguments to your JVM parameters in CF admin page?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess from my testing of CF 9 to solve a problem we are having, but it may just be the amount of RAM you have (and how much it is being used up).

I found that in CF 9, if you hit your memory limit, it will kill your JVM process automagically and restart it so all your memory is freed up.  (we have a problem with our older version of CF that just brings the server to its knees if the ram is maxed out).  Do you have a test environment where you can put a load on the server and see what happens when you max your RAM?

Comment: I've got a local test server, it runs Ubuntu instead of RHEL5 and it's the developer version of CF9 but I'll give it a go

Comment: Don't worry about it being the dev version. The production and Dev versions are exactly the same, it just has some connection limitations. To turn that into a prod box all you would need to do is enter a valid code, and wala! it's a fully functional box!

Comment: If it is a different OS than your production system, that may be an issue, you may not run into the same problems.

Comment: I do get the error on the local box occasionally during development, but not as often, as there are less users on it (only 3).

So what the best way to put a load on a server? Are there some simple command line tools I can use?

Comment: I usually make a simple page that calculates primes (but any process intensive page will do) and then use apaches jmeter to have it simulate a load of many users.  jmeter can be found @ http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/